# Sorting letters in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need a formula to sort letters in google spreadsheets. For example, if I have `A1:E1 (b,b,c,a,d)`, I would like them to be sorted in `F1:J1 (a,b,b,c,d)`.

I use this array formula `{=CHAR(SMALL(CODE($R5:$V5),COLUMNS($Z:Z)))}` to do this task in excel, I tried it in spreadsheets but it doesn't work. Any ideas, please?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)))`

Note:

- double `transpose` is used because `sort` function works for columns only.

Comment: Thanks @Max Makhrov. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

@Max's answer is the best one because it expands the array, but just for the record this does work in Google Sheets if you pull it across:

```
=ArrayFormula(Char(Small(Code($R5:$V5),Columns($A:A))))
```

It may be that the original formula didn't work because the default in Google Sheets is only to go up to column Z and you would need 4 columns to the right of that.

This would expand

```
=ArrayFormula(Char(Small(code($R5:$V5),COLUMN(R:V)-COLUMN(R:R)+1)))
```